# ImageButton and SharedPreferences / Preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences

I want to allow the user to select a website from Preferences in my Android app.
But when user choose a website from preferences list , imagebutton's image and its loadurl code must change.The image and loadurl should then remain the same even if the app closes.

now i ve preferences menu and values.but how can i change imagebutton's image and its url i dont know.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the info to shared preferences, then use an if statement to load the shared preferences. as in

```
if (preferences == websiteOne){
//load shared preferences  for websiteOne here
} else {
// load shared preferences for websiteTwo here
}
```

If you have more than two websites, you can set up a switch/case

EDIT

```
switch (website){
case websiteOne:
// shared preferences for websiteOne
imageView.setImageResource(imageResourceFromSharedPreferences);
url.setText(urlFromSharedPreferences)
break;
case websiteTwo:
// shared preferences for websiteTwo
break;
}
```

Do that for all 10 websites

EDIT 2

to set up a default sharedPreferences, in your onCreate() of an early activity, you can use

```
data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor e = data.edit();
        e.putString("website", websiteVariable);
        e.commit();
```

Do the same for the URL, and add these two variables `SharedPreferences data;` and `public static String filename = "fileName";`

Comment: thanks. i ve more than 10 sites.because i'm creating an app for read news.as i tried to say, im using this imagebutton as favourites.
so,the user will choose a website and (for example) 1st imagebutton will change..if i can figure out for first one then i think i can manage for other imagebuttons too.i really need someone helps..here 8.00 am and last 3 days im trying to do that and last night i didnt slept.

Comment: @billy gary ; thank you again.how can i set as default the imagebutton in sharedpreference and webview.loadurl?? thank u.you saved my day.